# Links stopped working when set server to parse HTML as PHP - Only when site seen on SmartPhones

Tags: php, hyperlink, html-parsing, smartphone

After adding this lines to .htaccess

```
AddHandler x-httpd-php .html .htm 
AddHandler php-script .php .html .htm
AddHandler php5-script .php .html .htm
AddType application/x-httpd-php .htm 
AddType application/x-httpd-php .html
```

My HTML started being parsed as PHP, but also my  LINKS  stopped working on mobilephones. This is so confusing! Also, when I see my resulting code after being parsed it looks fine, for example:

```
<div style="width:24%; display:inline-block; ">
            <div style="width:83%; ">
              <a href="compra_informes.html">
                 <img width="100%" src="img/i-cheques-prox.png">
              </a>
            </div>
</div>
```

Any comments on this are very much appreciated (thanks!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow a JS modal was invisible yet still covering my links and therefor these wouldn't work.

As strange as it sounds, now i have got them to work again.

Thanks for dropping by my question. Hope this helps!